# Zip files excluding log file

Tags: linux, perl, shell, unix, zip

I would like to zip all files inside a folder except log files with some format like '*_LOG_FILE*'. I am using below command in my shell script to zip the files.

```
usrl="/usr/bin/zip"; 
src_files="$2/*$1*"
tgt_file="$2/$1.zip"
exc_files="$2/$1*_LOG_FILE*"    
$usrl -jmn : $tgt_file $src_files -x $exc_files;
```

$2 holds the directory path and $1 holds the numeric value (it holds value like 82568 or 82659, etc.) which corresponds to the batch id value. Sample log file name is '823159_20160608_NM_LOG_FILE.dat' where 823159 is the batch id and the value is being replaced correctly without any issues.

The problem I am facing is, the log file has also been included in the zip file even though I have tried to exclude that in my code. Please advise some solution.

Comment: Drop the `$1` from `exc_files="$2/$1*_LOG_FILE*"`, i.e. change it to `exc_files="$2/*_LOG_FILE*"`.

Answer (score 0):

Id say add the files to an array, and loop through them. appending to the zip.

```
opendir(DH, $2);
my @files = readdir(DH);
closedir(DH);

foreach my $file (@files)
{
        # skip . and ..
        next if($file =~ /^\.$/);
        next if($file =~ /^\.\.$/);

        # Skip file containing that string
        next if $file =~ /.*(_LOG_FILE).*/);

        # Then append to the zip
        #....

}
```

I've not tested this. The alternitave is to copy the logs (in this array) to a temp directory, and zip that up.

Hope this helps